# How to find out a process gets end?

Tags: process

How can I tell when a given process exits? Like when it's done running and stuff.

For instance:

```bash
# Command 1
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso
```

```bash
# Command 2
echo "I'm a command"
```

How would I schedule to have `Command 2` run when `Command 1` exits?

Comment: by `end` do you mean when the process _exits_?  If so, you can use something like `while ! (pgrep -f 'wget.*ubuntu-14\.04-desktop' &> /dev/null); do echo 'waiting for program to exit'; done; echo 'program exited. :)'`

Comment: @AlexejMagura `end = terminated`

Comment: Got'cha.  A more correct term would be either `exits` or `terminates`, as in `when a program exits`.  `End`, while not _incorrect_, is an unusual way to describe program termination.

Comment: `echo $?` if the value of this command is 0 then your command is successfull runned.If it returns any other number, then it's not successfully executed.

Comment: If you want your 'scheduled' command to _only_ run when `wget` is successful, do something like this: `wget <URL> && CMD`.  If you only want `CMD` to get run when `wget` _fails_: `wget <URL> || CMD`.  And if you don't care whether `wget` fails or not: `wget <URL>; CMD`

Comment: And if you know the process ID (pid), you can schedule a command in any shell with `wait (pid); CMD`.

Comment: Why do people answer questions in comments instead of writing answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things that you could do here. The most basic thing that you can do on the command line is simply to join the commands Eg (using `sleep` instead of `wget`):

```
sleep 10; echo "Next command"
```

To do this in the background of the shell and make it possible to enter other commands while the process is running:

```
{ sleep 10; echo "Next command"; } &
```

To execute a command once any process that you know the PID of has finished:

```
wait $pid; echo "Next command"
```

And to background this:

```
{ wait $pid; echo "Next command"; } &
```